# Convert draw.io svg file to emf

Tags: svg, ms-word

I am using [this](https://www.draw.io/) tool, to build my diagrams. And I am capable of export as svg file. But when I use Inkscape the text will not appears. If I open the same file in chrome everything works good. Now I want to save this svg file as emf, to use it in MS WORD 2013. Any idea of how can i convert it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [this](http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToSvg.aspx) tool, is possible to converto to SVG without loss of data. 
Steps:

1. Export as SVG in draw.io
2. Use the SVG in some random test webpage
3. Use the [tool](http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToSvg.aspx)
4. Open the file in Inkscape